# PTIJ: Mrs Pots and Hagala

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If Mrs Pots drinks hot chicken soup, does she need to wait 6 hours before eating dairy? Or does she need to wait 24 hours for the flavors to go stale, and then go through Hagala to be able to eat dairy?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Thank you. I needed that.

Comment: I sure hope Mrs. Pots is Sefardi.

Answer (score 1):

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92_%D7%91

בצק שבסדקי עריבה, אם יש כזית במקום אחד, חייב לבער.

ואם לא, בטל במיעוטו.

וכן לעניין הטומאה, אם מקפיד עליו, חוצץ.

**ואם רוצה בקיומו, הרי הוא כעריבה.**

> With regard to dough that is in the cracks of a kneading bowl, if
> there is an olive-bulk of dough in one place, one is obligated to
> remove it. And if the dough does not add up to this amount, it is
> nullified due to its insignificance. And similarly, with regard to the
> halakhot of immersion to purify the bowl from ritual impurity, if one
> is particular about the dough that is stuck in the cracks and he plans
> to remove it and use it, it is a foreign substance that interposes
> between the kneading bowl and the water of the ritual bath, and
> invalidates the immersion of the bowl, leaving it ritually impure.
> **And if he wants the dough to remain in place, its status is like that of the kneading bowl itself and is not an interposition.**

From this we see that since the *blios* become part of Mrs Pots therefore they have a *din* of Mrs Pots and she doesn't need *hagalah*.

Answer (score 0):

If Mrs. Potts drank hot chicken soup, she would only need to wait the amount of time that those who live Deep in the Black Forest wait between dairy and meat. (I'm not sure if the castle is near Germany where [they'd wait](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/the-halachot-of-waiting-between-meals/) 3 hours or near the Dutch region where they'd wait 1 hour) Based on Rav Moshe Feinstein ([Igros Moshe OC 1:5 end](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=16)) who writes  with certainty that anything you can drink is below yad soledes, therefore the chicken soup flavor would not transfer.

[This also has almost-Purim-related (shloshim yom kodem hachag) practical ramifications with whether you must kasher your fillings before Pesach. See Rav Moshe Heinemann's Mah Nomar Hilchos Kashrus I (4:18)]